# Winzip hanging up in scheduled task batch file

Tags: batch-file, scheduled-tasks, winzip

I have a simple batch file as seen below that should extract a zip file to the root of E:.  The zip file is valid and I can run the batch file from the command line just fine.

Instead of completing the task, it continues to inform me that the Status is "Running".  The problem is, it is not running and the file never gets unzipped.

The task is running as a Domain Admin that has been specifically added as an Admin on the box.

Are there any known problems with using zip files in Scheduled Tasks.  I actually have this same problem on 3 out of the 12 boxes this task runs on, but there is no rhyme nor reason as to why some servers work, and others don't.

Any ideas on how to debug what is going on, or a solution would be very helpful.

Here is the batch file I'm attempting to run.

```
SET RootPath=E:
SET WinzipLocation=E:\Program Files\WinZip

"%WinzipLocation%\winzip32" -e -o  %CD%\TestZipFile.zip %RootPath%
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to use the [WinZip Command Line Support Add-on](http://www.winzip.com/prodpagecl.htm).

Answer (score 0):

what if you use 7-zip in command line?

Comment: Or any other tool capable of extracting a zip file. There are some available, see http://www.google.com/search?q=unzip.exe

Answer (score -1):

I realized after posting that the "bad" servers were all 64-bit.  I was running the 32-bit version of winzip.  Since the company I work for doesn't see the benefit in purchasing any software, I had no other option but to starting using 7-zip.  I have not tested for any performance increases or hits, but I do not that it works, regardless of the environment.

Thanks for the answers, but it looks like without the 64-bit version of winzip....i have no other options.